# How to Get username from SessionRegistry, it always returns ADMIN user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and I want to create a page that shows me all current users that are logged in.

For achieving this I have this code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String users(Model model)
{
    List<Object> loggedUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    for (Object principal : loggedUsers) {
        final User loggedUser = (User) principal;
        model.addAttribute("loggedInUser", loggedUser); 
    }

    List<Benutzer> users = userRepository.findAll();

    if(users !=null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("benutzern",users);
    }
    return "users";
}
```

However, I always get just the ADMIN user.

In 
    final User loggedUser = (User) principal; 
I always get my ADMIN user as well as my other user. So this works perfectly.

I think my problem is whithin the webpage but I do not know where exactly.

The following users are currently logged in:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Benutzername</th>
<th>Anzeigename</th>
<th>Dienstnummer</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<dl th:each="user : ${loggedInUser}">
<tr>
<td th:text="${user.username}">benutzername</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Maybe someone can point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after having asked the question I instantly found the solution.
I had to change the following line. I do not know how I was able to oversee this.

```
model.addAttribute("loggedInUser", loggedUsers);
```